# Wolves or foxes in Latin literature?

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, resource-request

I'm doing a research project and I'm examining comparisons between animals in different aspects of classical Latin literature. I was wondering if you had any suggestions for examples of wolves and foxes (not necessarily together, just in general) throughout Latin literature? I'm already using Phaedrus's fables. Thanks!

Comment: Hi BiblioCase, I'm pausing this question temporarily, since as it's written in will be prone to more discussion-based responses. At StackExchange, at least at the main site, questions should be relatively narrow and answerable with a correct answer. In light of that, this question can be edited to elicit a more definitive response. Are you looking for scholarly treatment of the topic, examples of any type, specific kinds of examples, or something else? Answering these questions here in the comments will better help us understand what you're after.

Comment: If you're unsure about this process, feel free to ping me in these comments (with `@cmw`).

Comment: You might want to give a look at [Plin. Nat. Hist. 8:80 ss](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Pliny_the_Elder/8*.html#80) re: wolves

Comment: Gee, Romans and wolves, I seem to recall there was something ...